# Converting existing numpy histograms into boost-histograms

Tags: python, numpy, boost, boost-histogram

I have a lot of [numpy (1d) histograms](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html). Each of them was created like this:

```
bin_height, bin_edges = np.histogram(data)
```

What is the best way to turn them into [boost-histograms](https://github.com/scikit-hep/boost-histogram)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution was suggested to me by [Hans Dembinski](https://github.com/HDembinski):

```
import boost_histogram as bh
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some randome data
rng = np.random.RandomState(10)
data = rng.normal(size=1000)

#create numpy histogram
bin_height, bin_edges = np.histogram(data)

#turn it into a boost-histogram
bhist = bh.Histogram(bh.axis.Variable(bin_edges))
bhist.view()[:] = bin_height

#plot it
plt.bar(bhist.axes[0].centers, bhist.view(), width=bhist.axes[0].widths);
```

Comment: Note that `bhist = bh.numpy.histogram(data, histogram=bh.Histogram)` is a better solution if the histograms are not already created.

Comment: `bhist[:] = bin_height` is supported since 0.6 or 0.7.